# Linspace not defined on python (jupyter)

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Python 2 on Jupyter and I'm attempting to edit my notebook.

I have the following code:

```
points=150
x=linspace(0,9*pi,points)
y=e**(-x/10)*cos(x)

plot(x,y,linestyle='None',marker=7,alpha=0.5)
show()
```

But an error appears:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-6ad78f0584e6> in <module>()
   1 points=150
-> 2 x=linspace(0,9*pi,points)
   3 y=e**(-x/10)*cos(x)
   4 
   5 plot(x,y,linestyle='None',marker=7,alpha=0.5)

NameError: name 'linspace' is not defined
```

I ran the notebook earlier on an institutional network with no error at all.

I'm a bit confused - what is the problem?

Comment: Have you ran all the cells above this piece of code? You need to run the line that imports numpy everytime you reopen the notebook to use linspace.

Comment: Did you import it from numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) function belongs to Numpy.  Try importing Numpy first.  By convention, it's generally imported as an entire module (`np`) and then functions are called within the `np` object:

```
import numpy as np

points = 150
x = np.linspace(0, 9 * np.pi, points)

x
# array([  0.        ,   0.18976063,   0.37952126,   0.56928189,
#          0.75904252,   0.94880315,   1.13856378,   1.32832441,
#        ...]
```

Note: Same goes for `pi`, should be `np.pi`.  The code you were using may have just done `from numpy import *`, which is why the `np.` prefix is missing from all the Numpy-specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the program and screenshot attached. Hopefully it will help.

```
from numpy import *
points=50
x=np.linspace(0,2*pi,points)
plt.plot(x,sin(x))
```

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this import for your code:

```
from pylab import *
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put below

x=np.linspace(0,9*np.pi,points)

instead of

x=linspace(0,9*pi,points)